# Run tux in a Sinatra App deployed in glassfish

Tags: ruby, console, glassfish, sinatra, jruby

I'm working on a rails application that uses a handful of Sinatra services each with their own database. We're in the process of moving our services and application to Glassfish. We are able to bundle our Sinatra app into a .war package and deploy it to a remote Glassfish service. One thing we want to do is be able to run [Tux](https://github.com/cldwalker/tux) in each of the services so we can interact directly with the objects (for debugging). I'd like to use the gems contained in the gems/gems directory within the glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/{app}/ directory. I tried writing a bash script based on this: https://gist.github.com/1986553/8e2d9ba892229ab076ad81ee88472d951b94282e, which ended up as follows:

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage:"
  exit
else
  DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
  echo $DIR 
  export GEM_HOME="${DIR}/gems/gems"
  export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME
  echo $GEM_PATH
  app_runner="java -cp lib/jruby-core-1.6.4.jar:lib/jruby-stdlib-1.6.4.jar org.jruby.Main -r ../META-INF/init"  # relative to app.war/WEB-INF/lib

  bundle exec tux
fi
```

It didn't appear to pick up the change to `GEM_PATH`. I put this approach aside, just installed in the necessary gems in an `rvm gemset` and set my environment to use it. I was then able to run `bundle exec tux`, but could not connect to the database without coping all the details that I set up on my Glassfish server. I was hoping to be able to use the jndi connector I'm using to connect in my Glassfish server.

Has anyone else done either of these things and/or have an pointers? Thanks

Comment: By 'Tux', do you mean the [Tux webserver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUX_web_server)?

Comment: Tux is a Sinatra console. https://github.com/cldwalker/tux